# lookup table in html

Tags: java, html

I am new to html, just need to modify an existing doc. I am looking for help creating a simple table in html that I am look up and get a value back.  Simple example A is the value and Apple is returned from the table.

thanks

Comment: please update your question with what have you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create a simple table using HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `<table>` tag initialized a new table. The `<tr>` tag creates a new row in the table. The `<td>` tag contains the text for a cell in the containing row. The `<th>` tag denotes a header item in the table and is not required.

For more information on HTML tables, look here:
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)